# How To Fix actual_version::result::failure 881 application author does not match debug token author?

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I ' am developing a Worklight application , I added a Blackberry 10 Environment and I want to run my app on a Device (Q5 in my Case).

The Problem is the bar package is created but the application cannot be installed because of the failure 881 Error . I'am using BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK to create and manage the Blackberry app .

this is the generated Log :

```
[WARN]    Failed to find debug token. If you have an existing debug token, please copy it to /Users/userName/.cordova/blackberry10debugtoken.bar. To generate a new debug token, execute the 'run' command.
[INFO]    Package created: /Users/userName/Desktop/Services/platforms/blackberry10/build/simulator/bb10app.bar
[WARN]    Failed to find debug token. If you have an existing debug token, please copy it to /Users/userName/.cordova/blackberry10debugtoken.bar. To generate a new debug token, execute the 'run' command.
[INFO]    Package created: Services/platforms/blackberry10/build/device/bb10app.bar
[INFO]    BAR packaging complete
[INFO]    Sending request: INSTALL_AND_LAUNCH
[INFO]    Action: Install and Launch
[INFO]    File size: 18414379
[INFO]    Installing Corporate_Services.testDev_te_Services72aafb38...
[INFO]    Processing 18414379 bytes
[INFO]    actual_dname::actual_id::actual_version::result::failure 881 no debug token found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error says **no debug token was found**.

So you have to create a debugtoken.bar and deploy into your device.

I hope you have followed the IBM Worklight documentation for Environment setup.

You have to **Create a debug token** the following steps will help you to do.

1. At a command prompt, navigate to `cordova-blackberry\bin\dependencies\bb-tools\bin` in your BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK folder.
2. Create a debug token for your device by using the following syntax and values for the command line options:

   > blackberry-debugtokenrequest -storepass {KeystorePassword} -devicepin {device PIN} {debug_token_file_name.bar}
   >
   > KeystorePassword - The password you defined when you created your developer certificate.
   >
   > device PIN   - The PIN of the BlackBerry device on which you want to install this debug token.

**Make the debug token available to the packager**

1. Create a copy of your debug token .bar file and name it debugtoken.bar.
2. Move the debugtoken.bar file to the root of the BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK installation folder.

**Install a debug token**

1. On the home screen of the BlackBerry 10 device, tap the Settings icon to open the System Settings screen.
2. In the list of options, select Security and Privacy.
3. In the list of security options, select Development Mode to view the Development IP Address.
4. At a command prompt, navigate to dependencies\tools\bin in your BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK folder.

*Type the following command:*

> blackberry-deploy -installDebugToken {path to debug token} -device {Development IP Address} -password {device password}

After the command executes, 
the result::success message displays indicating that you successfully installed the debug token.

Now you can try deploying the app.

[Blackberry HTML5 Dcoumentation - Deploy to a device](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v1_0/running_your_app_on_a_device.html)